# Does $L = \{a^n \ | \ n \geq 1, \ n \ \text{ is even or a square number}\}$ have infinite equivalence classes?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, notation

I am unsure if it has infinite equivalence classes or not, respectively how to interpret the textbook solution.

My approach was that it has infinite because,

lets say we have $x = a^5$ and $y = a^7$.

If we append them with $aa$ then
$x = a^7$ and thus $x \notin L$ and $y = a^9$ and thus $y \in L$. Because $9$ is a square number even though it's uneven and 7 is not even nor is it a square number.

So $x$ and $y$ must be in different classes and the infinite many classes could be written as:

$\{ [a^k] =\{ k \geq 0, \text{ k is uneven and not a square number}  \}\}$

and

$\{ [a^k] =\{ k \geq 0, \text{ k is even or a square number}  \}\}$

So in the end we have both those sets formed as union.

$\ $

My textbook says the solution is $\{[w] \ | \  w \in L(a^*)\}$.

Is this also infinite because we take every word out of $L$ or how can I understand the notation?

And if yes, would this be equivalent to my approach even though my set is "separated", but because in the end I formed a union with bot sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the description to "n is even or an odd square".

For every r, let $k = 4r^2$. $a^k a^j$ is in the language if j is even, or if j is odd and k+j is a square. The smallest odd j is $(4r+1)^2 - 4r^2 = 8r+1$. For every r, the smallest odd j is different, so we have an infinite number of equivalence classes.

(Actually, each exponent k gives a different equivalence class, because the the smallest j and the difference from the smallest to second smallest j will be different).

PS. Some explaining: If you give me a string x, I can determine all strings y such that xy is in the language. So for any string x, the set of strings y is interesting.

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ have the same set of y's that can follow, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be considered equivalent, and we can create equivalence classes for each different set of y's. If we move to a state machine, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be moved to the same state, but two x with different set of y's must move to different states. So a language is regular if there are only finitely many equivalence classes.

I personally prefer not to look at the x, but at the follow-sets, that is the possible sets of y's. The problem is the same, if the set of follow-sets is finite / infinite then the set of equivalence classes is finite / infinite. But it's often easier to argue that there are infinitely many different follow sets; I first showed that the smallest j so that $a^j$ is in a follow set gives infinitely many different values - enough to show the language is not regular.

Or you don't even need the exact follow sets. For example if you look for all strings that are the shortest string to add to some x to get a string in L, and show there are infinitely many different ones, or the shortest string with some Property P, that's enough to show L is not regular.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Would be the solution that I gave equivalent to the one from my book?